# Identify this Clock-Weather Widget

Tags: app-widgets

I've just found this photo on CNET:
[image]

I want to know which clock-weather widget app is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Motorola's default clock widget.
[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=F_WbJ6JNSiI) is a video that shows ,how can use this widget in other phones